# Prove that if $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$ and $g$ has a pole at $z_0$, then $f(z)g(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood of $z_0 \in \Bbb C$. Prove that if $f$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$ and $g$ has a pole at $z_0$, then $f(z)g(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z_0$.

Comment: Suppose the singularity were non-essential. Then ...

Comment: Hint: Since $g$ has a pole, can you write $g(z)=(z-z_0)^{-k}\overline{g}(z)$?  What if $f(z)g(z)$ also had a pole, could you prove that $f(z)$ also has a pole (or is defined)?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Sorry I'm not sure how to prove $f(z)$ also would have a pole, though I can see you want to prove $z_0$ is neither a pole nor a removable singularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch: Since $g$ has a pole at $z_0$, we can write $g(z)=\frac{\overline{g}(z)}{(z-z_0)^k}$ where $\overline{g}(z)$ is nonzero in a neighborhood of $z_0$.  Suppose that $f(z)g(z)$ has a pole or a removable singularity (if it has a removable singularity, then remove it).  Then $f(z)g(z)=\frac{h(z)}{(z-z_0)^l}$ where $l$ may be zero.  Then, $f(z)=\frac{h(z)}{(z-z_0)^{l-k}\overline{g}(z)}$ (why can we write this?).  Therefore, $f$ is defined at $z_0$ or has a pole.